# How to display GeoWebCache local tiles with OpenLayers 3?

Tags: geoserver, openlayers

I've created local tiles using GeoWebCache and they are inside local folder names :

`Layer  - EPSG_4326_9-
                     - 19_10 - 
                             - 0608_0339.png
                             - 0608_0340.png
        - EPSG_4326_10 - 
                       -19_10 -
                              -1217_0679.png
                              -1217_0680.png
        - EPSG_4326_11 -
                       -38_21
                             -2435_1358.png
                             -2435_1359.png`

How can I show them using OL ?
I thought using XYZ layer , something like :

```
var test =  new ol.layer.Tile({
title: 'test',
type: 'base',
visible: true,
source: new ol.source.XYZ({
    tileUrlFunction: function (coordinate) {
        if (coordinate == null) {
            return "";
        }
        var z = coordinate[0];
        var x = coordinate[1];
        var y = coordinate[2];
        //var y = (1 << z) - coordinate[2] - 1;

        return 'tiles/layer/EPSG_4236_' + z + '/' + x + '/' + y + '.png';
    }
})
```

});

but the Z X Y numbers don't match ....

Answer (score 1):

There is an outstanding pull request which should give you a good idea on how to achieve this: https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/pull/3241/files

Comment: There is also a [Leaflet implementation of GWC tiles](https://github.com/damienlabat/leaflet-geowebcache-plugin/blob/master/src/Leaflet_GWC_Layer.js) that should be easy to understand and re-implement.